# Use Maven project in Android Application

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I develope a litte Android Application for SDK 22+

Now I want to use a API to a website.

The API is written in Java and use maven for build.

I am absolutly new in maven.

Is there a way to use the maven api in my gradle based android studio project?

I'm testing since two days to import this api, but without success.

---

**UPDATE 1**

The API I want to use is the [api-themoviedb](https://github.com/Omertron/api-themoviedb)

I want to use SDK 22 because of the apache HttpClient support.

I tried to merge the api with my project. But I didnt had success.

Comment: Maven and Gradle artifacts are perfectly compatible; you should usually just need to declare the dependency in your Gradle build. You'll need to post more details if you want help.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for your help, I append some informations to my question. Please tell me what for informations you need in addition :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build.gradle for your app, add
`compile 'com.omertron:themoviedbapi:4.0'`

Comment: Are all packets in my gradle build maven repositorys?

Comment: Most of them, yes. Gradle is able to use maven resources. You might want to read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction.html